# How to compute the following Complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I am trying to compute the following complex-valued integral $(1.3.10)$ by using contour integration and the residue theorem. The substitution is shown right below $(1.3.10)$ and the answer is shown in $(1.3.11)$. By goal is to reproduce $(1.3.11)$.

[image]
$$

Since $-\pi < k < \pi$ the contour integration should be clockwise around the unit circle. I will be using the residue theorem which is based on counterclockwise contours. We see
$$
P(x,z) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{e^{-ikx} dk}{1 - z(pe^{ik} + qe^{-ik})} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\text{clockwise}} \frac{w^x idw/w}{1 - z(pw^* + qw)} = \frac{i}{2\pi}\int_{\text{clockwise}} \frac{w^{x-1}dw}{1 - z(pw^* + qw)}
$$
$$
= -\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_{\text{counter clockwise}} \frac{w^{x-1}dw}{1 - z(pw^* + qw)} = \text{sum of residues}
$$

The above seems to suggest that for $x < 1$ there are additional poles at $w = 0$, and so it seemed that $P(x,z)$ would have two forms, one for $|x| < 1$ and $|x| \ge 1$, but the answer seems to give one form for $P(x,z)$.

**Does that mean $w = 0$ is never a pole regardless of the value of x?**

**How do I get the final answer?**

Comment: Does the text say what the bounds for $p$, $q$, and $z$ are?

Comment: @Accelerator p,q are between 0 and 1 inclusive. No bounds for z because it is a z transform variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already stated, the change of variable $w = e^{-ik}$ leads to
$$
P(x,z) 
   = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{e^{-ikx}}{1 - z(pe^{ik} + qe^{-ik})} \mathrm{d}k 
   = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{w^{x-1}}{1 - z(pw^* + qw)} \mathrm{d}w
$$
where $C$ is the unit circle. Now, we would like to apply the residue formula at some point; however, it is forbidden, because the integrand depends on the complex conjugate $w^*$. Fortunately, one has $w^* = w^{-1}$ on the unit circle, such that
$$
P(x,z) = -\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{w^x}{qzw^2 - w + pz} \mathrm{d}w
$$
Let's suppose $x \ge 0$ for the moment. Then, the integrand admits two first-order poles coming from the equation $qzw^2 - w + pz = 0$, hence $w_\pm = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4pqz^2}}{2qz}$; their residues are given by
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathrm{Res}_{w=w_\pm}\left(\frac{w^x}{qzw^2 - w + pz}\right)
   &=& \displaystyle 
   \lim_{w\rightarrow w_\pm} (w-w_\pm)\frac{w^x}{qzw^2 - w + pz} \\ 
   &=& \displaystyle 
   \frac{w_\pm^x}{qz(w_\pm-w_\mp)} \\
   &=& \displaystyle 
   \frac{\pm1}{\sqrt{1-4pqz^2}} \left(\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4pqz^2}}{2qz}\right)^x
\end{array}
$$
since $qzw^2 + w - pz = qz(w-w_+)(w-w_-)$ by factorization. Note that the poles can lie inside or outside the unit circle $C$ according to the range of the variables $p,q,z$ $-$ which you haven't specified here. In the present case, the authors seem to consider $w_-$ only, so that
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
P(x,z) 
   &=& \displaystyle
   -\frac{1}{2\pi i} \cdot 2\pi i \,\mathrm{Res}_{w=w_-}\left(\frac{w^x}{qzw^2 - w + pz}\right) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4pqz^2}} \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4pqz^2}}{2qz}\right)^x
\end{array}
$$
Finally, in the case where $x \le 0$, consider the change of variable $w = e^{+ik}$ instead, so that $e^{-ikx} = w^{-x} = w^{|x|}$ cannot generate a singularity at the origin. Then, apply the same procedure as above and you will end up with the expression given by the authors.

Comment: Thank you so much!!